# Spin 3/2 along an arbitrary direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

> Consider a particle of spin 3/2. Find the matrix for the component of the spin along a unit vector with arbitrary direction n. Find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I know that the general spin operator is
\begin{equation}
    \widehat{S} = a\cdot \widehat{S}_x + b\cdot \widehat{S}_y + c\cdot \widehat{S}_z
 \end{equation}
and that
\begin{equation}
\hat{n} = (\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta},\cos{\phi})
\end{equation}
Along with
\begin{align}
 \widehat{S}_x &\stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sqrt3 & 0 & 0 \\ \sqrt3 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & \sqrt3 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt3 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\
 \widehat{S}_y &\stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{2i}\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sqrt3 & 0 & 0 \\ -\sqrt3 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & \sqrt3 \\ 0 & 0 & -\sqrt3 & 0\end{pmatrix} \\
 \widehat{S}_z &\stackrel{\cdot}{=} \hbar\begin{pmatrix}3/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -3/2\end{pmatrix}\ .
\end{align}

So then we get
\begin{equation}
\hat{n}\cdot \widehat{S}  \stackrel{\cdot}{=} \frac{\hbar}{2}(\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta})\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sqrt3 & 0 & 0 \\ \sqrt3 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & \sqrt3 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt3 & 0\end{pmatrix}\ + \frac{\hbar}{2i}(\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta})\begin{pmatrix}0 & \sqrt3 & 0 & 0 \\ -\sqrt3 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & \sqrt3 \\ 0 & 0 & -\sqrt3 & 0\end{pmatrix}\ + \hbar(\cos{\phi})\begin{pmatrix}3/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -3/2\end{pmatrix}\ .
\end{equation}

Now, I know I should determine the secular equation (characteristic equation) after adding the matrices and find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues from there, but I keep getting long and complicated equations that don't seem to factor. Is there any shorter method or any other way to do it?

Comment: I am not too sure what you are referring to. Do you mean : \begin{equation}
    \widehat{S}_z =  \cos{\theta} \widehat{S}_x -  \sin{\theta}\widehat{S}_y
 \end{equation}